# How to open task pane after once closing in App for Office 2013 Excel

Tags: excel, office365

If I close the task panel in my App for Office 2013 Excel as exemplified on the following screen shot, then how can I reopen it?

[image: task panel closing screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Insert Tab in excel. 
Then select "My Apps"
The drop down next to my apps will show your most recent ones (this will work for debug mode)
if you were in debug mode make sure to save the excel doc or template so that it will open up on the following debugger start.

Comment: Hey Dan, can you help me with my this question related to same excel project. No one is helping me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501425/how-to-deploy-my-office-ad-in-app-or-excel-app-on-local-system-so-that-it-will-w